# Making an Associative Table of Unique Identifiers

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create an associative table on a sheet that is pulling in data from a different sheet. By associative I mean, if the data is changed in the source data sheet, it would be reflected on the new sheet. I also want to only have the new sheet's table to be contingent on having a certain unique value. In my case, I want to pull up information related to a part number. The original source data will have many rows that contain the same part number, but I only care to display one of them.

This is what I have so far:

```
Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function
Dim ref() As Variant
Dim row As Integer
row = 92
Worksheets("Part Tracking Scorecard").Activate
While Cells(row, 6).Value:
    If IsInArray(Cells(row, 6).Value, ref) Then
        row = row + 1
    ElseIf Not IsInArray(Cells(row, 6).Value, ref) Then
        ReDim Preserve ref(1 To UBound(ref) + 1) As Variant
        ref(UBound(ref)) = Cells(row, 6).Value
        Worksheets("Unique Parts").Activate
        ?????
        row = row + 1
```

To satisfy my condition to only showcase the unique part numbers, I initialized an empty array called "ref". Then, as I iterate through the source sheet, I would check if the part number was in ref with the function "IsInArray". If it was in it, it would move onto the next row, if it wasn't add the part number into the empty array and move to the next row.

The portion with the "????" is where I'm having most of my issue trying to figure out. That part is supposed to be where I make the new table with the date from the unique part number. The very simple and tedious thing I could do is make some loop to run through the columns of the rows and put in a vlookup function. I was wondering if there may be a more robust or more elegant way in doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've had the right reflex tyring to define an array to stock your values. Here are a few tips of how I would get around to doing it (not perfect, but it should help you out):

```
Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
   IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function

Dim Source as Worksheets
Set Source = Worksheets("Part Tracking Scoreboard")
Dim ref1(), ref2() As Variant
Dim row, index, index2 As Integer

row = 92

ref1 = Source.Range(Worksheets(Source.Cells(row,1), Source.Cells(lastrow, last column))
'Start by placing your ENTIRE source sheet in ref1, if your source sheet is big, this will help you win A LOT of time during the looping phase. Notice how I start from row 92 seeing as this is where you started your loop
'lastrow and lastcolumn represent the position of the last cell in your source file

For index = row to lastrow
    If Not IsInArray(ref1(row, 6).Value, ref2) Then  
        ref2(index) = ref1(index) 'copy the entire row from source to ref2
Next index

Dim NewFile as Worksheet
Set Newfile = Sheets("NewSheetName")

Dim ref2dimension_x, ref2dimension_y as Integer 'find dimensions of ref2 array
ref2dimension_x= UBound(ref2, 1) - LBound(ref2, 1) + 1
ref2dimension_y = UBound(ref2, 2) - LBound(ref2, 2) + 1

For index = 2 to ref2dimension_x 'go through entire new sheet and set values
    For index2 = 1 to ref2dimension_y
        NewFile.Cells(index, index2).Value = ref2(index - 1, index2)
    Next index2
Next index

ref1() = nothing
ref2() = nothing 'free up the space occupied by these arrays
```

I was not sure about what you were trying to do exactly during the else loop. If you intention is to copy the entire row, this should work. If you want to copy only specific data from the source sheet, you will need to find the indexes of the corresponding columns (hardcode them if they are not going to budge, or use a loop to find them through string comparison otherwise).

Comment: This seems like its heading in the right direction for me. The else function is where I would switch to a new sheet and past in the row data. Rather than copying and pasting in the ref2 array into a new sheet, would there be anyway way it could have an automatic live feed from the source?
EDIT: The ref2 is just a structure to help filter out for unique parts?

Comment: I added the for loop that should allow you to paste into the new sheet. This might need a bit of tweeking as I did not get around to testing it. If you need to do array re-arrangement you can easily do it with ref2 before exporting the values to the the new sheet.
For the automatic live feed, you need to call the sub in which you have written this code everytime a modification is applied to your source sheet. Just look for the moment where these modifications are brought about, and call this sub at that moment to apply the changes also to your new sheet.

Comment: After messing around with your code,  I was wondering how you would fix the for loop for indexing to find unique values. When you place the data into an array, it becomes a 2D array . With that, the index coordinates for values would probably change once you put the original value into ref1. I'm kind of at a loss with how to really create the parameters to iterate through ref1.

Comment: Normally when you put your values in ref1, if, for example, you have a file of 10 rows and 5 columns, and you want to select the values from the 5th column on all the rows, you could loop for it with:

`for index = 1 to 10 'first row to last row`
    `uniquevalues = ref1(index, 5)`
`next index`

This should only select the values from the 5th column. All you have to do is find the column number corresponding to the unique values and that should do it. Also I made a mistake in my code last night so I modified it (in the first for loop)

Answer (score 0):

This solution combines some macros that I use frequently (so even if you don't use them now, they might be helpful in the future). It won't work if the data in the unique table needs to be "live", but if it'd be sufficient for it to be updated whenever the workbook is opened/closed (or on demand), this is a lot less complicated than the array version.

Basically you just:

- Copy the main/unduplicated table to a new sheet
- Remove duplicates by part number
- Remove unnecessary columns from unduplicated table (if applicable)

I'm assuming that your source data is in a formal Excel Table (ListObject). Just swap out "PartTable" for whatever your actual table is called.

```
Sub makeUniqueTable()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim MainWS As Worksheet
    Set MainWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Part Tracking Scorecard")

    Dim UniqueWS As Worksheet
    Set UniqueWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Unique Parts")

    UniqueWS.Cells.Clear

    Call cloneTable(MainWS.ListObjects("PartTable"), "UniquePartTable", UniqueWS)

    Dim UniquePartTable As ListObject
    Set UniquePartTable = UniqueWS.ListObjects("UniquePartTable")

    Call removeDuplicates(UniquePartTable, "Part Number")

    'Optional: remove unnecessary columns by listing columns to be deleted...
    'Call deleteColumns(UniquePartTable, Array("Unnecessary Column 1", "Unnecessary Column 2"))
    '...or kept:
    'Call deleteColumns(UniquePartTable, Array("Part Number", "Manufacturer", "Product Description"), True)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub cloneTable(tbl As ListObject, newName As String, Optional newWS As Worksheet = Nothing)
'Copies a table (tbl) to a new worksheet (newWS) and gives it a name (newName)
'If there is any data in newWS, the new table will be added to the right of the used range
'If newWS is omitted, new table will be added to same worksheet as original table

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastColumn As Long
    Dim newRng As Range
    Dim newTbl As ListObject

    If newWS Is Nothing Then
        Set ws = tbl.Parent
        lastColumn = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set newRng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, lastColumn + 2), ws.Cells(1 + tbl.ListRows.Count, lastColumn + tbl.ListColumns.Count + 1))
    Else
        Set ws = newWS
        If ws.ListObjects.Count > 0 Then
            lastColumn = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            Set newRng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, lastColumn + 2), ws.Cells(1 + tbl.ListRows.Count, lastColumn + tbl.ListColumns.Count + 1))
        Else
            Set newRng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(1 + tbl.ListRows.Count, tbl.ListColumns.Count))
        End If
    End If

    tbl.Range.Copy
    newRng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Set newTbl = ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, newRng, , xlYes)
    newTbl.Name = newName

End Sub
Sub removeDuplicates(tbl As ListObject, Optional colName As Variant = "")
'Removes duplicates from a table (tbl) based on column header names (colName()) provided by user
'If no column names are provided, duplicates will be removed based on all columns in table

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    If Not IsArray(colName) Then
        If colName = "" Then
            ReDim colNumArr(0 To tbl.ListColumns.Count - 1) As Variant
            For i = 0 To tbl.ListColumns.Count - 1
                colNumArr(i) = tbl.ListColumns(i + 1).Range.Column
            Next
        Else
            ReDim colNumArr(0 To 0) As Variant
            colNumArr(0) = tbl.ListColumns(colName).Range.Column
        End If
    Else
        ReDim colNumArr(0 To UBound(colName) - LBound(colName)) As Variant
        j = 0
        For i = LBound(colName) To UBound(colName)
            colNumArr(j) = tbl.ListColumns(colName(i)).Range.Column
            j = j + 1
        Next
    End If

    tbl.Range.removeDuplicates Columns:=(colNumArr), Header:=xlYes

End Sub
Sub deleteColumns(tbl As ListObject, ByVal colName As Variant, Optional invert As Boolean = False, Optional sheetCol As Boolean = True)
'Deletes column(s) from sheet based on header names (colName) from a table (tbl)
'Will result in error if provided column contains multiple tables
'colName can be a String or an array of Strings
'Inverted mode deletes all columns *except* those in colName

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim x As Boolean

    If Not IsArray(colName) Then
        tempStr = colName
        ReDim colName(1 To 1) As String
        colName(1) = tempStr
    End If

    If invert = False Then
        For i = LBound(colName) To UBound(colName)
            If sheetCol = True Then
                tbl.Parent.Columns(tbl.ListColumns(colName(i)).Range.Column).Delete
            Else
                tbl.ListColumns(colName(i)).Delete
            End If
        Next
    Else
        For i = tbl.ListColumns.Count To 1 Step -1
            x = False
            For j = LBound(colName) To UBound(colName)
                If tbl.HeaderRowRange(i).Value = colName(j) Then
                    x = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            If x = False Then
                If sheetCol = True Then
                    tbl.Parent.Columns(tbl.ListColumns(i).Range.Column).Delete
                Else
                    tbl.ListColumns(i).Delete
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```